# SendFailedException: bad password

Tags: java, email, smtp, gmail, jakarta-mail

This question has evolved to a more definite question from a rather vague one.  The code comes from an [example by mkyong](http://www.mkyong.com/java/javamail-api-sending-email-via-gmail-smtp-example/).  At least according to Google, [it's a bad password](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=14257), and I've followed their login suggestion.  Of course, I get the same result when putting in the correct password, the password below is a dummy.  It's the same output regardless of the password.

Output:

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 1 second
-- listing properties --
mail.smtp.gmail=smtp.gmail.com
mail.smtps.quitwait=true
mail.smtp.username=hawat.thufir@gmail.com
mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
mail.smtp.connectiontimeout=2000
mail.smtp.user=hawat.thufir
mail.smtp.socketFactory.class=javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory
mail.smtp.password=password
nntp.host=nntp://localhost/
mail.smtp.socketFactory.port=465
mail.smtp.timeout=2000
mail.imap.port=993
mail.imap.timeout=5000
mail.smtp.port=587
mail.smtp.auth=true
mail.imap.host=imap.gmail.com
mail.nntp.newsrc.file=/home/thufir/.newsrc
mail.imap.connectiontimeout=5000
mail.smtp.host=smtp.gmail.com

========message follows==========

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.mail.SendFailedException: Send failed;
  nested exception is: 
    javax.mail.SendFailedException: 5.5.1 http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=14257 g6sm55120721pat.2 - gsmtp
    at net.bounceme.dur.nntp.SendTLS.sendMessage(SendTLS.java:61)
    at net.bounceme.dur.nntp.SendTLS.<init>(SendTLS.java:23)
    at net.bounceme.dur.nntp.SendTLS.main(SendTLS.java:34)
Caused by: javax.mail.SendFailedException: Send failed;
  nested exception is: 
    javax.mail.SendFailedException: 5.5.1 http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=14257 g6sm55120721pat.2 - gsmtp
    at javax.mail.Transport.doSend(Transport.java:231)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:75)
    at net.bounceme.dur.nntp.SendTLS.sendMessage(SendTLS.java:57)
    ... 2 more
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/MailFromNNTP$
```

code:

```
public class SendTLS {

    public SendTLS() {
        try {
            sendMessage();
        } catch (NoSuchProviderException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(SendTLS.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (MessagingException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(SendTLS.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(SendTLS.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SendTLS();
    }

    private void sendMessage() throws NoSuchProviderException, MessagingException, IOException {
        Properties props = PropertiesReader.getProps();
        props.list(System.out);
        System.out.println("\n========message follows==========\n");
        final String username = props.getProperty("mail.smtp.username");
        final String password = props.getProperty("mail.smtp.password");
        Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
                new javax.mail.Authenticator() {

                    @Override
                    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
                    }
                });
        try {
            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("from-email@gmail.com"));
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse("to-email@gmail.com"));
            message.setSubject("Testing Subject");
            message.setText("Dear Mail Crawler,\n\n No spam to my email, please!");
            Transport.send(message);
            System.out.println("Done");

        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is port a Integer (and not a string ? Just guessing :P) ? Also try replacing getDefaultInstance with Session.getInstance(props). Also if that doesn't help. Try props "mail.smtp.connectiontimeout" and "mail.smtp.timeout" and set a limit to get a stacktrace. Often it is  a firewall/Port/Network issue

Comment: line 58 is the connection:  `transport.connect(host, port, user, password);`   and, port is an int, by the way.  I  I tried with correct password, of course.
`

Comment: I know this has been through a few revisions. It's quite odd, paring down the properties file to the bare minimum actually **introduces** errors into `SendTLS`.

Comment: I have no idea about this, my last attempt, are you using 2 step login ?

Comment: no, just regular login.  I'm going to try tomorrow again, not tls though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are connecting to Gmail. Use these properties

```
prop.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true"); 
prop.put("mail.smtp.host", host); 
prop.put("mail.smtp.user", from); 
prop.put("mail.smtp.password", pass); 
prop.put("mail.smtp.port", "465"); 
prop.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
```

Also go through this http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes

```
*Post was modified after answering, answer may no longer be relevant*
```

Comment: Leave a comment, if this doesn't help :)

Comment: I'll try this, looks interesting.  Why would I need an authenticator, or is that as much a debugging tool, to get more output?  (ie, bad password, etc.)

Comment: is this an inner class?  inside `Gmail`?  Or, in same .java file as `Gmail` but not inner?  or, in its own .java file?  http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/mail/Authenticator.html#getPasswordAuthentication%28%29  is protected

Comment: It could be a inner class inside Gmail in this case. See this, on when you need a authenticator and when you don't

Comment: @Thufir : Could you run your code as it is (without authenticator and stuff) with the following line modified : transport = (SMTPTransport) session.getTransport(); Run it as it is without the "smtp" part. I think this could be the error

Comment: it seems to need the smtp, without that parameter I get:  `javax.mail.NoSuchProviderException: Invalid protocol: null` but I'll check into that.  (also, because `PasswordAuthentication` is protected I'm having some difficulty compiling.  I can't override, because I'm in the wrong package (I think).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43827/discussion-between-thufir-and-caadi0)